# problems with eval() in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, eval

I get this syntax error on the eval line in this code when running IE. This works perfectly fine in both Chrome and Firefox, just not IE.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/isLoggedIn.php',
        success: function (tmp) {
            data = eval ('('+tmp+')');
            if (data.login=='OK') {
                $('#main').load ('scripts/loginok.php');
                $('#menu').show("slow");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Please help me understand this problem

Comment: what is the content of `data`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? and why do you think `eval` is the way of doing it?

Comment: if thats json data then you could use jquery json for parsing....

Comment: its json data either {"login":"NOPE"} or
{"login":"OK"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method that parses the data automatically:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  $.getJSON('scripts/isLoggedIn.php',
    function (data) {
      if (data.login=='OK') {
        $('#main').load ('scripts/loginok.php');
        $('#menu').show("slow");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$.parseJSON(tmp);
```